# Замена значений по условию

Tags: php, twig

На сайте слайды и описание хранятся в БД и некоторые колонки в таблице имеют англ.версию. Например, text и text_en, content и content_en.
После выполнения запроса я вывожу слайды на страницу таким образом:

```html
$slider = $db->getAll("SELECT text, text_en, content, content_en FROM main_slider");

{% for item in slider %}
<div class="какая-то верстка">
{{ item.text }}
</div
{% endfor %}
```

Как можно в twig менять по условию (в зависимости от наличия en в урле) {{ item.text }} на {{ item.text_en }} ?
Я подумал просто добавить функцию на проверку en у урла и потом в шаблонизаторе по условия менять, что нужно, но не хочется кучу if добавлять на страницу. Может есть какие предложения?

Comment: `{{ item.text | default(item.text_en) }}`